# Can I reattach or suspend a BindingExpression without warnings?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-3.0

I have the following test case xaml.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="testDS1">
        <x:XData>
            <root xmlns="">
                <item>1</item>
                <item>1</item>
            </root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testDS1},XPath=/root/item}"/>
    <Button Content="Change" Click="OnChangeClicked"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This displays a listbox of numbers. I then execute this code.

```
    public void OnChangeClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDataProvider ds = Resources["testDS1"] as XmlDataProvider;
        string xml = "<root><item>1</item></root>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        ds.Document = doc;
    }
```

This causes this warning to appear.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 43 : BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.; XPath='/root/item' BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='XmlDataCollection' (HashCode=40644060); target element is 'ListBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') XmlDataCollection:'MS.Internal.Data.XmlDataCollection'
```

However, the ListBox is bound correctly and has the correct values. From reading this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/711d3735-34c7-4358-8787-958752bcaabe), its mentioned that this behaivour is normal and the binding expression has reattached. How do i eliminate this warning ? I have tried BindingOperations.ClearBinding but even that triggered this warning. Should i just live with this warning ?

Comment: Have you tried using DynamicResource rather than StaticResource?

Comment: i think i cant. Binding source is not a DependencyProperty. I get this exception when i do. 

A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found an answer

```
public void OnChangeClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataProvider ds = Resources["testDS1"] as XmlDataProvider;
    string xml = "<root><item>1</item></root>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    using(ds.DeferRefresh())
    {
       ds.Document = doc;
       ds.XmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    }
}
```